# Namespace for XInclude included elements

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, xml-namespaces, xinclude

Consider these two XML documents:

#### a.xml

```
<a xmlns="foo" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <xi:include href="b.xml" parse="xml" />
</a>
```

#### b.xml

```
<b>Hi Mom!</b>
```

**What namespace should the `<b>` element be in after inclusion**, `foo` or no namespace?

---

Using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) to load the first document with XInclude processing produces a text representation that would imply that `<b>` is in the parent namespace, but inspecting the elements claims that `<b>` has no namespace:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'

d = Nokogiri.XML(IO.read('a.xml'),&:xinclude)
puts d
#=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
#=> <a xmlns="foo" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
#=>     <b>Hi Mom!</b>
#=> </a>

p d.root.namespace
#=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x3fd40c517de8 href="foo">

p d.root.elements.first.namespace
#=> nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What namespace should the `<b>` element be in after inclusion, foo or no namespace?

No namespace.  XInclude operates at the infoset level and preserves the infoset properties of the included content.  The [infoset specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/) explicitly makes the point that

> An information set corresponding to a real document will necessarily be consistent in various ways; for example the [in-scope namespaces] property of an element will be consistent with the [namespace attributes] properties of the element and its ancestors. **This may not be true of an information set constructed by other means; in such a case there will be no XML document corresponding to the information set**, and to serialize it will require resolution of the inconsistencies (for example, by outputting namespace declarations that correspond to the namespaces in scope).

(my bold) - the `<b>` element is not in a namespace, but its *in-scope namespaces* infoset property is no longer consistent with the namespace declarations in the "virtual" document that results from resolving the XInclude.